# Redux-form: FieldArray overwrites initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have an array of objects each having a id property (readonly) together with some other editable property.
I render this with a FieldArray but what I get is that the readonly property is overwritten cause it has no registered field.

Here's my code

```
const renderRoomNameTranslations = ({ fields, roomNames }) => (<div>
    {fields.map((roomName, index) => (
        <Field component="input" name={`${roomName}.it`} />
        <Field component="input" name={`${roomName}.de`} />
        <Field component="input" name={`${roomName}.en`} />
    ))}
</div>);

<FieldArray name="content.roomNames" component={renderRoomNameTranslations} />
```

Below my initial state, roomId is the readonly field which can't be edited and it's paired with some other information in my data model:

[image]

Here's what happens when the "de" field is changed:

[image]

And finally the updated status where "it", "en" and "roomId" fields are gone:
[image]

Is there way to keep the untouched field (especially "roomId" field which can't be edited so has no Field)? Any direction?